# Jasmine SyntaxError Unexpected token import when require test source file

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jasmine

I'm trying to write a test suite for a js module

Here's my spec.js

```
describe("First one", function() {
    var dm = require('../path/to/DateManager.js');
});
```

Here's the test source file

```
import X from './X';

var DateManager = function(templates, config, someCallback) {
    this.templates = templates;
```

Here's the error.

```
> jasmine

Started
......F

Failures:
1) First one encountered a declaration exception
  Message:
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

I read about something to do with ES6 but I've installed jasmine-es6 as a helper and it still throws the error

Here's my jasmine.json

```
{
    "spec_dir": "spec",
    "spec_files": [
        "**/*[sS]pec.js"
    ],
    "helpers": [
        "../node_modules/jasmine-es6/lib/install.js",
        "helpers/**/*.js"
    ],
    "stopSpecOnExpectationFailure": false,
    "random": false
}
```

Comment: how did u figure this out?